# Soundcloud API SC.stream (track not loading)

Tags: soundcloud

I'm streaming music from the soundcloud API, and sometimes when I call SC.stream the track does not stream and I get the error:

"GET http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/80608808/stream?client_id=78bfc6a742a617082972ddc5ef20df2a 404 (Not Found)"

The GET request works for some tracks and not for others. I cannot figure out why or if there is an issue with the SC API.

He is a replication of my problem on plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TMVWGg

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the URL that you supply as a parameter to `SC.stream`?

Comment: I get the URL from a track object that is returned from an SC.get call, (the URL from the SC.get call I get from parsing the track id out of a Soundcloud widget)

Comment: He is a replication of my problem on plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TMVWGg

Looking at plnkr, when play1 is called, the console prints out

"GET http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/78971940/stream?client_id=af5b4d4236354009bd1525a974bd7e79 404 (Not Found)"

while when play2 is called the song successfully plays.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some soundcloud tracks are not streamable via api. You can check this for each track by property "streamable".

Comment: Not necessarily true. Even "streamable" tracks can come back 404.

Comment: True, but this is probably desirable behaviour

Comment: I agree with @AJcodez it does happen even with streamable songs

Comment: some tracks stream in js api with firefox but not on chrome, could be browser related